# Panels missing after Ubuntu 11.04 Upgrade

Tags: ubuntu

i decided to upgrade my Ubuntu 10.10 to the latest release of Ubuntu which is the 11.04, after the installation, the Ubuntu required me to restart, after the boot, my Ubuntu desktop was nothing but a background, there are no panels, launcher, anything.

I Googled my problem, and they said that i will just select Ubuntu classic on the login screen, so that i can access my launcher and panels, and that solved my first problem, the other problem is.

I want to experience and use the new feature of Ubuntu 11.04 the Unity 2D , how to enable this? without experiencing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to diagnose. There could be a lot of things.

One thing I would check is my shell startup scripts. Rename your ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc, start a new shell, and see if it improves things.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is default in 11.04,I had too upgraded from 10.10,initially I had problems like OS getting hung.But I don't have any problem. . .

Comment: run sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: run sudo apt-get update